# 2D array passed into JsonResult doesn't give me 2d array in json

Tags: c#

Hi I have the following 2d array in c#

```
   int[,] data = new int[3, 2] { { 0, 1690 }, { 1, 1696 }, { 2, 1659 } };
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Is there a reason why I get the following json

```
[0,1690,1,1696,2,1659] instead of [[0,1690],[1,1696],[2,1659]]
```

I need this because that's what flot expects.

Comment: Have you tried to return a jagged array instead?

Comment: wow thanks my Chinese brother. I worked it out myself totally.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] data = new int[3, 2] { { 0, 1690 }, { 1, 1696 }, { 2, 1659 } };
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```